# Module unavailable when compiling another file that uses it in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml

I have multiple compilation units in OCaml, one of which is causing a few problems. One compilation unit has two files foo_one.mli and foo_one.ml, these compile without any errors when using `ocamlc`. The other compilation unit has two files shoo.mli and shoo.ml. shoo.ml needs to make use of functions from foo_one, and so in the file shoo.ml I use `open Foo_one`. To compile, I use the command `ocamlc foo_one.mli shoo.mli shoo.ml` and the compiler returns the error: Module Foo_one is unavailable (required by Shoo).

What is causing this error and how can it be solved?

I made sure that the compilation units are all in the same directory, with the files in one compilation unit having the same name and capitalising the name of the module I am including in shoo.ml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've compiled `foo_one.mli` and `foo_one.ml` with:

```
ocamlc -c foo_one.mli foo_one.ml
```

Then you should be compiling `shoo.ml` with:

```
ocamlc foo_one.cmo shoo.mli shoo.ml
```

If you had provided the `-c` option, you could compile with the following because you're not yet ***linking*** the two, and thus `Shoo` only needs to know the interface `Foo_one` exposes.

```
ocamlc -c foo_one.mli shoo.mli shoo.ml
```

If you did this, you could finally link the two together to create an executable with:

```
ocamlc foo_one.cmo shoo.cmo
```